# Flutter issue on reusing stateful widget and updating state

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this busy button logic where on api calls, I can replace the widget by loading indicator in event of network requests until it completes.

```
_BusyButtonState buttonState;

class BusyButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final onTap, text;
  BusyButton({Key key, this.text, this.onTap});
  @override
  _BusyButtonState createState() {
    buttonState = _BusyButtonState();
    return buttonState;
  }
}

class _BusyButtonState extends State<BusyButton> {
  bool isBusy = false;
  void notLoading() {
    setState(() {
      isBusy = false;
    });
  }

  void loading() {
    setState(() {
      isBusy = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return isBusy
        ? CircularProgressIndicator(
            valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation(Colors.blue),
            strokeWidth: 1.5,
          )
        : RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child:
                Text('${widget.text}', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
            onPressed: widget.onTap);
  }
}
```

And I have listview builder where I am using this button on each item to change the status of the item from active to inactive and vice versa.

```
BusyButton(
  key: UniqueKey(),
  text: active?"Inactive":"Active"
  onTap: () {
      sendToServer(active?true:false)
   },
)

sendToServer(bool active) async{
try {
      updateState.loading();
      var response = await CallApi().putData(
          {"active": active.toString()}, "url");
      if (response.data['success']) {
        updateState.notLoading();
        print("done");
      } else {
        updateState.notLoading();
        print("error");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      updateState.notLoading();
      print(e);
    }
}
```

But when I try and press the button, it works if network request is successful but loading indicator appears on some random button across the listview. Also it throws following error on request fail.

```
E/flutter (25919): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose(): _OutlinedButtonState#971b3(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use setState.

```
BusyButton(
      key: UniqueKey(),
      text: active?"Inactive":"Active"
      onTap: () {
         setState(){
          sendToServer(active?true:false)
         }
       },
    )
```

Comment: The whole reason I went through creating separate widget was to avoid UI rebuild and to rebuild button only for busy state. So, any other option?

Comment: How can you rebuild lisview while avoiding? You can try something like wrap your listview with StatefulWidget and setState for only that, see it's document here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulBuilder-class.html

Comment: In this case I am not trying to rebuild listview at all. I am just trying to change the button to loading during request period and back to button after request is completed. I will try and see if stateful builder helps.